# Safely run a pump using the driver/controller built into an air conditioner - switch EMC motor for a pump motor

Tags: pwm, ac-dc

I am attempting to switch an ultra-efficient household air conditioner from air cooled to liquid cooled.  The unit, (LG DUALCOOL with Watt Control-Eco - T06EV4), was attractive because it has 3 power settings - 215, 312 or 419 watts. This is ideal for my off grid application in a boat.

I think I have the HVAC side figured out. However, the brain box in the AC needs to control the cooling of the loop to manage its own head pressure. This is normally done with a 3 wire, 6 pole, 240v, 26w fan.

The solution is to have the AC control a pump instead of the fan - on/off, or fast/slow.

I am told on an HVAC forum:

- "That’ll be an inverter driven fan, not just on/off."
- "That is an ECM motor. The driver/controller will know if its not present. You won't find a pump to match the driver."
- You won't find a pump to match the driver/controller. They are paired. Depending on the model, that controller may be a direct part of the main control board. Sometimes they are separate and you might be able to reverse engineer the serial comms The motor is an ECM, so it's much more than just PWM. The controller is looking for back EMF at the right phase angle and speed or it'll lock out.

Question 1: Is this true?

If it is true;

Question 2 :

Is there a way to take the signal from the driver/controller and modify it to run a pump that is out of spec.?

12 V DC is preferred.  I have considered a micro controller to command a PWM dc motor controller when to jump and how high based on the corresponding signals from the AC driver/controller.  This would also have to be done without upsetting the AC and causing errors.

I also thought of leaving the AC fan connected and using an IR Sensor with Arduino to measure RPM of the shaft to tell the DC pump what to do though that is not great for efficiency or compactness.

Here are some more photos:
[image]
[image]

Comment: that looks a lot like a single speed fan motor.

Comment: We need to know some things about the application: Is 240V available? Can a 240V pump simply be used? Is 240V wholly unavailable thus the preference/requirement for 12V? How is the output designed: contact closure, SSR, etc.? Could it simply be rewired for 12V output, or will additional investigation (potentially reverse engineering) of the control board be necessary? And, is this a good idea, does the proposed solution make sense in the greater system? Will any temperature or pressure or voltage or whatever sensors need to be adapted?

Comment: 240v is available.  I am told on an HVAC forum:
"That’ll be an inverter driven fan, not just on/off."
"That is an ECM motor. The driver/controller will know if its not present. You won't find a pump to match the driver."
but if Jasen Слава Україні is right and it is a single speed motor then how does that change things? 
I could not find a pump that is 3 phase AC, and about 25w 
could i just use a relay some how?  I don’t see why the aircon would bother having a variable speed fan????  it would be much better for me if it was single speed.  can anyone confirm that fan is single speed?

Comment: Unless there is some load sense, you should be able to connect a dummy load and sense V or f depending on drive type and use that to speed control whatever you want to replace it with.

Answer (score 0):

It's a 2 wire split phase fan motor, It should be possible to substitute a 240V pump of 0.35A or less.

Comment: It has 3 wires going into it... maybe one is a Protective Earth?

Comment: blue and yellow are the supply red goes to the capacitor, if you have a 2 wire pump don't connect the capacitor.